# Spring MVC 3.1 - Model Attribute lost

Tags: spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a quick question on scope of ModelAttributes.

Dev. Env: Spring MVC 3.1/Java 6/JSP w/JSTL for Views

In my controller, I add an attribute to the model via

```
model.addAttribute(“appForResubmission”, appForResubmission);
```

In the JSP(served out in response to a GET request) I read it’s contents as:

```
${appForResubmission.appId}
```

— works fine and the data is shown on JSP as expected.

Upon submission of the JSP, in the same controller in a different method(in response to a PUT request), I try to read the attributes from the Model for any changes and I am doing this as

```
@ModelAttribute(“appForResubmission”) Application app
```

in the method signature.

However, all I get is a new Application object when I try to interrogate the object for data. Spring’s documentation says this kind of instantiation of a new object happens when the requested attribute does not exist in the Model.

What would cause the attribute to be lost? Any ideas? I am suspecting it is a scope issue someplace but I am not sure where the problem could be.

Any pointers you could provide is greatly appreciated?

Thank you,
M. Reddy

Answer (score 2):

The scope of a `modelattribute` is the `request`, internally it is just equivalent to `HttpSerletRequest.setAttribute("model", model)`.

If you want the model to be available in a different controller you probably have two options, one is to reconstruct it, based on what you submit to the controller or using your persistent source. The second option is for specific model attributes to be added to the session using `@SessionAttribute({'modelname'})`, but just be careful that you have to call [SessionStatus.complete](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/SessionStatus.html) to remove the model added to the session later.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In my case I am working with just one controller. The two methods that I am using are mapped to the same URL except for one method responds to a GET and the other one to a POST. I am adding a model attribute in the GET and then upon return from the JSP(via POST), I am trying to retrieve the same attribute.

Comment: Yes, but do you have fields in the JSP to hold all the fields of your `Application` object and do you submit all those fields back to the the method which handles your `PUT`, if not then they will not be available in the method handling `PUT`.

Comment: Yes, I have the fields in the JSP...<input type="text" value="${appForResubmission.appId}" name="appId"/>. Not all fields are displayed on the JSP though.